# fsockopen errors com SSL

Tags: php, openssl, fsockopen

Pois bem eu tenho um código que no wamp server php 7.3.1 funciona sempre.
Quando subi para um centOS rodando CWP7 php 7.3.2 o mesmo código não funciona

$config['protocol'] = "smtp";

```
    $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
    $config['smtp_user'] = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_pass'] = "xxxxx";
    $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
    $config['mailtype'] = "html";
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";




    $this->ci->load->library('email');

    $this->ci->email->initialize($config);        
    $this->ci->email->to($email);
    $this->ci->email->message($messagem);


    $this->ci->email->bcc("xxxx");
    $this->ci->email->from('xxxx', 'xxxx');
    $this->ci->email->subject($titulo);
    $res = $this->ci->email->send();
    echo $this->ci->email->print_debugger();
```

Ai solta está mensagem de erro:

```
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)
```

No CWP tem segundo o php o modulo openssl está lá.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

J´[a busquei varias soluções e não encontrei nenhum...
Alguem tem alguma ideia do que eu posso tentar?

Answer (score 0):

Acabei encontrando o motivo como tinha habilitado o firewall as portas 465 e 587 estavam bloqueadas então fui no firewall do CWP e habilitei o trafego de saída pelas portas 465 e 587. Antes só era permitido trafego de entrada por elas.